# Atualizando dados de uma activity para outra

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Estou fazendo um aplicativo `android` que utiliza comunicação `telnet` e recebe dados a cada segundo (`ActivityTelnet`). Eu gostaria de tratar parte desses dados em outra `activity`(`Activity1`). Porém, quando estou na `Activity1` não sei como continuar recebendo a atualização desses dados, não sei nem se é possível. Alguém pode me informar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

É possivel usando um BroadcastReceiver ou forçando o conteúdo para a outra activity através de uma Intent.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14017720/how-to-pass-value-using-intent-between-activity-in-android

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html